# Mongoose reassign array attribute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't understand why Mongoose `find` result references cannot be reassigned.

**eg:**

```
Ticket.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, ticket) => {
    console.log("before: ", ticket)
    ticket.tasks = [1, 2] //won't work
    ticket.title = "foo"
    console.log("after: ", ticket)
    console.log("=========")
    let copyTicket = ticket.toObject()
    console.log("Solution after: ", copyTicket)
    copyTicket.tasks = [1, 2]
    copyTicket.title = "bar"
    console.log("Solution before: ", copyTicket)
})
```

**Output**

```
before:  { tasks: [],
  _id: 5aa17051e97eac407b72757a,
  title: 'ho'
  }
after:  { tasks: [],
  _id: 5aa17051e97eac407b72757a,
  title: 'foo',
  }
=========
Solution after:  { tasks: [],
  _id: 5aa17051e97eac407b72757a,
  title: 'foo',
  }
Solution before:  { tasks: [ 1, 2 ],
  _id: 5aa17051e97eac407b72757a,
  title: 'bar',
  }
```

Do you have any ideas how and why there is this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried using calling the [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method on the query chain?

Comment: Does that mean object returned by Mongoose are not plain js object? So why does a typeof answer Object, the console.log look exactly as a regular js object? I found this behavior really confusing! Plus modify primary type is working but not reference...

Comment: Documents returned from Mongoose are not plain objects but model objects (Document)

Comment: @JulienLeray ofc a typeof gonna say it's an object, because it is. Console.log is calling the `toString()` method of the object and so display to you the pretty data. Now do a `Object.keys(ticket).forEach(x => console.log(ticket[x]));` you will see the mongoose additionnal keys